# use php dbo to display data by referencing row and column number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in mysql_* you could use the following to display a specific row and column:

`mysql_result(3,2)`

This would show 3rd row, second colum of result set.

I have a php pdo script to display some mysql data:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT name, surname FROM people"); 
$sth->execute(); 
$row = $sth->fetch(); 
$name=$row[name];
$surname=$row[surname];
```

The above would work well if I had a single result for the query. if I have multiple results, how could I fetch the name and suraname for a specific row and column.

So if I wanted row 11, column 0 and row 11, column 1 (name and surname from row 11) what would my syntax be?

Thanks as always for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need certain rows you should use `LIMIT` in your query to narrow returned dataset. Alternatively you can use `fetchAll()` but this uses more resources than needed, so `LIMIT` would both speed things up and reduce resource usage.

PS: your array usage is wrong. You should be doing `$row['name'];` not `$row[name];`. Or use `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` (or `fetchObject()`) and then access properties like this `$row->name;`

**EDIT**

`fetchAll()` returns array, with both numeric indexes and column name indexes. So accessing columns 0 and 1 of 11th row would look like this:

```
$dataArray = $sth->fetchAll();
$name = $dataArray[10][0];
$surname = $dataArray[10][1];
```

or (which is better):

```
$name = $dataArray[10]['name'];
$surname = $dataArray[10]['surname'];
```

Note, rows are 0 indexed, hence `10` not `11`.

Comment: Thanks @WebnetMobile, appreciate the feedback. I actually need to populate a table with the data, so I need to return all rows, will be 50 maximum. but need to call each row seperately. if I used fetchALL(), how could I output each of these one at a time? similar to mysql_Result? Thanks again.